# How can I add new attributes to a particular instance?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How can I add new attributes to a particular instance ?

For example here I want to add attr_acessors methods to attributes "m1","m2" in object e1 and "m4".."m6" to e2

```
e1=Element.new("e1",["m1","m2"])
e2=Element.new("e2",["m4","m5","m6"])
e1.m1 = "try"
puts e2.m4
```

To allow this :

```
class Element
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize name,meths=[]
    @name=name
    meths.each do |m|
      #?? 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
meths.each do |m|
  singleton_class().class_eval do
    attr_accessor m
  end
end
```

where the `singleton_class()` method is defined as:

```
def singleton_class
  class << self
    self
  end
end
```

(you probably want to make it private).

This will create the accessors only on the specific instance rather than on the Element class.

Comment: Thx Jonathan. That is my favorite solution ! I was struggling with something similar this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple OpenStruct instead?

```
require 'ostruct'
e1 = OpenStruct.new
e1.m1 = 'try'
```

Alternatively, you can add attribute to any object using:

```
a.instance_eval('def m2; @m2; end; def m2=(x); @m2=x;end')
```

If you want to add attributes to all instances of specific class you can also:

```
a.class.instance_eval('attr_accessor :mmm')
```

Comment: ostuct force me to modify my object inheritance. Thx anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
methods.each do |method|
 class << self
  attr_accessor method
 end
end
```

This way, you get rid of the extra method definition and `class_eval` because `class << self` already puts you into the scope of the eigenclass, where you add singleton methods.